# Ember-CLI tests can't include modules from 'app' directory

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ecmascript-6

I am trying to include a module in my app from one of the tests. Is it even possible to do that? I am only able to include a module in the 'tests' directory.
I keep getting the infamous "Could not find module" error.

`http://localhost:4200/assets/test-support.js:5578:16: Could not find module d3graph/app/controllers/index imported from d3graph/tests/unit/utils/graph-helper-test`

This is my test code:

```
import { moduleFor, test }  from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';
import helper from '../../../app/anything/anywhere';  // <- THIS LINE FAILS

moduleFor('util:graph-helper', 'Graph Helper', {
  beforeEach: () => initialize()
});

function initialize() { /* something */ };

test('test desc', function(assert) {
  var testObj = this.subject();

  // test logic follows
});
```

I did try various modifications of the path to the module, including absolute path from root, I even tried including via 'require()', but alas without success.
Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shouldn't be a problem. You will need a `needs` line inside your `moduleFor` call:

```js
import { moduleFor, test }  from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';

moduleFor('util:graph-helper', 'Graph Helper', {
    needs: ['controller:index'],

   beforeEach: () => initialize()
});

function initialize() { /* something */ };

test('test desc', function(assert) {
    var testObj = this.subject();

    // test logic follows
});
```

See http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/testing-controllers/#toc_testing-controller-needs for more details about `needs`.

#### Edit

Disregard the above information... that's for Ember modules which resolve the standard way. To include modules off the beaten Ember path, a simple ES6 import will suffice (this example demonstrates pulling in `some-util` for the `controller:index` unit tests):

```js
import { moduleFor, test }  from 'ember-qunit';
import Ember from 'ember';
import SomeUsefulUtil from '<application-name>/utils/some-useful-util';

moduleFor('controller:index', 'Graph Helper', {
   beforeEach: () => initialize()
});

function initialize() { /* something */ };

test('test desc', function(assert) {
    var testObj = this.subject();

    // Create utility class instance
    var someUsefulUtilInstance = new SomeUsefulUtil();

    // test logic follows
});
```

The potentially non-intuitive part of this is that you have to prefix the import with your application's name instead of the standard `app` directory.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that 'needs' property, I just don't understand how can I use that referenced module (the one in 'needs'). Suppose I specified a helper module named, say `util:graph-loader`, that exports an object with some utility functions. Using `subject.get('util.graph-loader')` obviously won't help me, is there something else I may try?

Comment: See my revised answer. I hastily answered before realizing that the 'utils' directory isn't part of the standard test resolver.

Comment: the non-intuitive part is really helpful on the last line is really helpful. thanks